# How can I populate jagged array with chars in c#

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, streamreader

I am struggling to populate jagged array with chars
My goal is to read string. slice them into chars, then populate jagged array with those chars

```
            "Lorem",
            5,
            new char[][]
            {
                new char[] { 'L', 'o', 'r', 'e', 'm' },
            },
```

or

```
            "Loremipsumdolorsitamet",
            5,
            new char[][]
            {
                new char[] { 'L', 'o', 'r', 'e', 'm' },
                new char[] { 'i', 'p', 's', 'u', 'm' },
                new char[] { 'd', 'o', 'l', 'o', 'r' },
                new char[] { 's', 'i', 't', 'a', 'm' },
                new char[] { 'e', 't' },
            },
```

like the example. above ints under the string represent arraySize(i.e. number of columns) and streamReader(see code under) is the string itself. I am using System.IO and System.Text

```
        var read = streamReader.ReadToEnd().ToCharArray();
        if (read.Length == 0)
        {
            return Array.Empty<char[]>();
        }

        char[][] jagArray = new char[read.Length / 5][];

        for (int p = 0; p < read.Length; p++)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < read.Length / arraySize; i++)
            {
                jagArray[i] = new char[arraySize];

                for (int j = 0; j < arraySize; j++)
                {
                    jagArray[i][j] = read[p];
                }
            }
        }

        return jagArray;
```

I tried this code, but obviously it doesnt work.

Comment: _"I tried this code, but obviously it doesnt work."_ - Obvious to _you_. SO expects a more verbose explanation of the discrepancy between the expected result versus the actual result, though. Maybe imnprove your question with the help of [ask].

Comment: Try using a `List<char>` instead of an array.

Comment: You my (if allowed) also consider [Span<T>.Slice](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.span-1.slice?view=net-6.0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this method to split a single `char[]` array into array of arrays, each of which is no longer than `cols` characters length:

```cs
public static char[][] ToJaggedArray(char[] chars, int cols)
{
    int rows = (chars.Length + cols - 1) / cols;
    char[][] jagArray = new char[rows][];
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        jagArray[i] = new char[Math.Min(cols, chars.Length - cols * i)];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < chars.Length; i++)
    {
        int row = i / cols;
        int col = i % cols;
        jagArray[row][col] = chars[i];
    }

    return jagArray;
}
```

Comment: thanks, i adjusted it to my code and it worked

Answer (score 0):

```
string str = "Loremipsumdolorsitamet";
int slice = 5;
List<List<char>> list = new List<List<char>>();
List<char> list2 = new List<char>();
int limit = str.Length/5 +1;
for (int i = 0; i < limit; i++)
{
    if (str.Length <= 5)
    {
        slice = str.Length;
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < slice; j++)
    {
        list2.Add(str[j]);
    }
    str = str.Remove(0, slice);
    list.Add(list2);
    list2 = new List<char>();
}
```

Hopefully I understood you correctly, This is my very scuffed way of doing it, hopefully some of the more experienced users can provide some info to improve this.

EDIT. OUTPUT:

```
foreach(var a in list)
{
    foreach (var b in a)
    {
        Console.Write(b + " ");
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}

L o r e m
i p s u m
d o l o r
s i t a m
e t
```